# What versions of JVM are recommended for Storm

Tags: java, jvm, apache-storm

Do JVMs 7 and greater work well with Storm? Are there any gotchas I need to be aware of? I vaguely remember reading something about this before, but for the life of me, I cannot find any information on it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using JVM 7 and up, you are in the safe side, remember to run nimbus and supervisor with the same version as the target version of your topology, i.e. if your target is Java 7, nimbus and supervisors should be running versions 7 or 8. If you choose the target to be Java 8, then you should run JVM 8.

Furthermore, if you are starting a new project you might want to check this [notice for Oracle not providing more updates in Java 7](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml).

Hope this helps,

Jose Luis

Answer (score 2):

If possible, choose the latest Java 8 version, as with the new JMM (Java Memory Model) it will be in most cases better than the old JMM with PermGen (Java 7 and below, it is suppressed in Java 8).

You will be able to use Java 8 JMM along with garbage collector G1 which will probably be the best way to deal with latencies due to garbage collection. It will be more time-predictable and should be a great concern for any real time system (like Apache Storm of course). It is also way easier to tune memory and garbage collection in java 8  (just my opinion) with jstack and jvisualvm.

Answer (score 1):

I think JVM 7 can work well with Storm.You can view this tutorial http://jansipke.nl/getting-metrics-from-the-java-virtual-machine-jvm/